# Open a thread in the Service and use Handler to send Message to Activity, the NullPoint error appear

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

In the MainActivity, I use `startService(intent)`to start a Service. In the Service I open a Timer to get data(the data I say here is assumed to be time) once every two seconds, then I open a Thread in the Timer to store this data into the `ArrayBlockingQueue`instance beacause I am afraid that operation of storing data will block the thread that gets the data. I will use the data to show in a customized ViewGroup in which three textView was placed vertically. In fact, my real demand is real-time display before 2 seconds, the first 4 seconds, the first 6 seconds of data. I am a new Android developer and this problem has bothered me for a long time and I hope someone can give me help. Thanks a lot!

Here are all my source code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TemperatureCarouselView mView;
    private TextView temp, tv1, tv2, tv3;
    public static Handler mHandler;
    public static int FLAG = 1;
    private Intent timeService = null;
    public static BlockingQueue<String> data = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(4);
    Object object[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature);
        mView = (TemperatureCarouselView) findViewById(R.id.tempView);
        tv1 = mView.getTv1();
        tv2 = mView.getTv2();
        tv3 = mView.getTv3();


        timeService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataService.class);
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                String str = (String) msg.obj;
                if (msg.what == FLAG) {
                    temp.setText(str);
                    tv1.setText((CharSequence) object[1]);
                    tv2.setText((CharSequence) object[2]);
                    tv3.setText((CharSequence) object[3]);
                }
            }
        };
        startService(timeService);
        object = MainActivity.data.toArray();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(timeService);
        mHandler.removeMessages(FLAG);
    }
}
```

**DataService.java**

```
public class DataService extends Service {
    private Timer timer = null;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
    private String Data = "0";
    private static final String TAG = "DataService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        init();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = MainActivity.FLAG;
                msg.obj = getTime();
                Data = (String) msg.obj;
                Log.i(TAG, "run:  timer----"+Data);
                MainActivity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                DataThread getData = new DataThread();
                getData.start();
            }
        }, 0, 2000);
    }

    private String getTime() {
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }

    private void init() {
        timer = new Timer();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }



    class DataThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    MainActivity.data.put(Data);
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: getData---"+Data);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The Error Information**

03-23 02:59:52.642 3841-3855/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
Process: com.zhiyu.temperaturecollection, PID: 3841
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4bcc.png)

Comment: Memory leaks.... Why are you using static handler from MainActivity in Service?

Comment: Broadcast emitter and receivers are used to communicate from service to activity/fragment. Static variables look easy to implement, but cause big damage to your app.

Comment: @MohammedAtif So you mean I better use Broadcast？

Comment: Yes, exaxtly. use broadcast. thats how service communicates with activity

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I will try! @MohammedAtif